# Можно ли в android studio переименовать метод сразу для всего проекта?

Tags: android-studio

Если возникла необходимость переименовать метод, есть ли способ изменить имя метода так, что бы везде где он вызывается он так же переименовался?

В частности у меня есть метод:

```
public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, UUID crimeId){
    Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, CrimePagerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID, crimeId);
    return intent;
}
```

И я хочу, что бы имя метода как-то отражало имя класса к которому он принадлежит, что-то в духе `newIntentCPA`. Есть ли способ изменить имя метода, без необходимости выискивать все места, где он применяется?

Comment: Выделите нужный метод, нажмите ПКМ (правая кнопка мыши) -> Refactor -> Rename

Comment: @NorthFace Благодарю.

Comment: @NorthFace напишите ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Выделите нужный метод.
2. Нажмите **ПКМ** (правая кнопка мыши).
3. Нажмите **Refactor**.
4. Нажмите **Rename**.